Error uploading assets into GEE: error code 3
I am getting an error while trying to upload a shapefile into Google Earth Engine.

Error: Projection exception. Ensure the projection is specified
correctly and the coordinates are within its valid area. Detailed
error: Unable to transform edge (437817.000002, 3912969.000002 to
437816.999924, 3912969.000281) from EPSG:4326 PLANAR to EPSG:4326.. (Error code: 3)

I have checked that the projection of my shapefile several times and it matches that of other shapefiles that have been successfully uploaded as assets into GEE. I'm quite confused.
Does anyone know how to help resolve this issue?

As commented by @Vince:

If the file is marked as being WGS 1984 decimal degrees, and has a Y
coordinate of 3.9 million degrees, the projection metadata is
incorrect.


In my case when I uploaded the ".shp" file a prompt requested the ".dbf" and the ".shx" and I assumed that was enough, but it turned out that EE also needed the ".prj" to understand what reprojection/transformation to apply. I'm quite sure that's what happened in your case because I got an identical Error message
